# Embedly API call not wanting to work in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I make this call in my application.js file but it doesn't seem to return a dynamically generated embedded video from the link the user inputs:

```
$("#new_video").bind('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var q = $(this).find('#video_video_url').val();
        if (q == '')
            return false;

        $.embedly(q, {maxWidth: 500, wrapElement: 'div' }, function(oembed, dict){
            if (oembed == null)
                $(".video").html('<p class="text"> Not A Valid URL </p>');
            else 
                $(".video").html(oembed.code);
        })
    });
```

I'm not exactly sure what's supposed to go where `'submit'` is, so that may be whats causing me trouble.

My id of the form that the user inputs the url into is `#new_video`, the field's id is `#video_video_url`, and the class `video` is generated from my video partial:

```
<%= div_for video do %>
<% end %>
```

This is rendered in my `index` view, where I'd like to display all the embedded videos. This is all there is in my `index` view where I want all the videos to be embedded:

```
<div id ='video_div'>
  <%= render @videos %>
</div>
```

however, it's not working. No video is being embedded. What am I doing wrong? Bear in mind that I not only want to embed the video once the url is submitted, but I store the url and want to display the embedded videos indefinitely into the future.

Here's the HTML of the form that the browser sees in the `new` view:

```
<div id="dialog" class="window" style="top: 237px; left: 435px; display: block; ">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/videos" class="new_video" id="new_video" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="h/yzzD0lWsp7nc89WPmDRXWs5ahdfUc3ZvY5IukX2fQ=">
</div>
<div class="field">
   <label for="video_video_url">Video url</label><br>
   <input id="video_video_url" name="video[video_url]" size="30" type="text">
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <input id="video_submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Video">
</div>
</form>
<a href="#" class="close">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

I get this error in the console:

```
 Started GET "/jquery.embedly.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Mar 17 00:09:29 -0700 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/jquery.embedly.js"):

 Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.1ms)
```

I include jquery.embedly.js in my application layout though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is that it's not loading the Embedly jQuery script. Is that resolved? Alternatively you can load the Embedly jQuery script from our hosted http://scripts.embed.ly/jquery.embedly.js page.

Answer (score 0):

What's the HTML look like?  are you sure you want to use .val() on #video_video_url and not html() or attr('href')?  I think you use .val() for input values.

From the val() jquery docs: "The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements."

UPDATE: Just saw your description and you did say it's from user input.  So disregard above.  Can you paste the HTML?

UPDATE #2: it might be a problem with loading the embedly script.  are you using the min version?  could you check to make sure the filename is the same?  seems that if jquery gets loaded, it should also load embedly as well.

Comment: I want to retrieve the url string that the user has input into the form field and put it into the variable q so I can pass it to Embedly...

Comment: what happens when you do below on submit?

    console.log($('#video_video_url').val();

Also, I don't think you need to do $(this).find, just straight up $('#video_video_url').val().

Comment: I jsfiddled and it looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/koesbong/PLUMT/1/.  I wonder if it's the $.embedly()

Comment: hmmm, there's this error: Started GET "/jquery.embedly.js" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Mar 17 00:09:29 -0700 2011

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/jquery.embedly.js"):
  

Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.1ms)

Comment: which is weird because I have this in my application layout: `<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.4.2.min', 'jquery.embedly.js', 'rails', 'application' %>`

Comment: before .html(oembed.code), try doing console.log(oembed.code) and see if that returns anything.

Comment: Ahh ... that might be why.  I am not familiar with rails, so I can't help with how to load assets correctly.

Comment: ok, can you upvote the question so more people come to it pleasE?

Comment: upvoted, but why does my answer get downvoted?  i helped debug  :-(

Comment: ahh ok sorry, but it's telling me I can't undo it unless you edit your answer

Comment: oh, so if you include jquery this way 'jquery-1.4.2.min' without the js in the end, shouldn't you also include embedly this way 'jquery.embedly' instead of 'jquery.embedly.js'?